# How to position the the y coordinate of the input component?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, position, user-experience

Here is the UI Prototype I am trying to implement 
[image]

Here is what I currently have: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54cwezo6/7/)

and my CSS code for controlling the position of  the input component

```
input {
   background-color:red;
  transform: translateY(-200px); 
  padding: 0px;
  transform: translateX(-120px)
 }
```

The input tag isn't lining up correctly. What made the most sense to me to use here is the  [CSS Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) property but translateY and translateX seem to undo each other. 
 I was able to line up the x position of the component up with

```
      transform: translateX(-120px)
```

but whatever value I am inputting into translateY isn't having an effect.

Does anyone know what arguments inputted into translateX and translateY will achieve the effect I want. Should I use a different CSS property to do this?

Comment: Is table not an option?

Comment: @divy3993  Thanks table is a better option for this. I adjusted my code. Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/users/3761297/committedandroider

Comment: At what should i take look?

Comment: @divy3993 wow sorry i posted a link back to my profile. I resolved the issue. thanks!